# Interpreting output from glmer Model in R including odds ratios and /or plotting data?

Tags: r, data-visualization, generalized-linear-model

maybe someone could help me with interpreting my Output from the glmer Model in R? In general I would use the Odds Ratio for interpretation- am I right? However, since it is below 1 I am not sure how to handle it?

I also have been struggling to plot my data correctly. Maybe someone has any ideas for this?

I would really appreciate any help or adivce.

Variables:

- (Veraenderung_pos)dependent: Reaction of child (positive/neutral)
- (Maske)independent: Wearing a Mask (Not wearing one/wearing one)

R-Output:

```
> summary(H1_T2x)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: Veraenderung_pos ~ Maske + (1 | VP)
   Data: Data_T2x

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   209.0    218.4   -101.5    203.0      167 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.1298 -0.4901 -0.4103  0.7500  1.7910 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 VP     (Intercept) 2.07     1.439   
Number of obs: 170, groups:  VP, 72

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)  -0.7258     0.3299  -2.200   0.0278 *
Maske        -0.2998     0.4102  -0.731   0.4650  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
      (Intr)
Maske -0.549
> Anova(H1_T2x, type=3)
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III Wald chisquare tests)

Response: Veraenderung_pos
             Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)  
(Intercept) 4.8395  1    0.02781 *
Maske       0.5339  1    0.46496  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> #H1: Konfidenzintervalle, Koeffizenten, odds ratio #####
> #confidence intervalls
> seH1 <- sqrt(diag(vcov(H1_T2x)))
> 
> 
> # table of estimates with 95% CI
> (tabH1 <- cbind(Est = fixef(H1_T2x), LL = fixef(H1_T2x) - 1.96 * se, UL = fixef(H1_T2x) + 1.96 *
+                 seH1))
                   Est        LL          UL
(Intercept) -0.7258004 -1.372455 -0.07914585
Maske       -0.2997611 -1.103823  0.50430057
> 
> #odds ratio
> exp(tabH1)
                  Est        LL        UL
(Intercept) 0.4839371 0.2534839 0.9239052
Maske       0.7409952 0.3316010 1.6558270
```

Comment: There's nothing "odd" about an odds ratio less than one.  It just means that the probability of an event is lower in the test group than in the control group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say something like "the odds ratio for the effect of wearing a mask was 0.74 (95% CI: 0.33 - 1.65). This means that the estimated effect was to slightly decrease the risk of positivity (from a probability of 0.33 without masks to 0.26 with masks), but the measured effect was not statistically significant -- the data are also consistent with masks *increasing* the risk of positivity".

A couple of notes:

- the probability calculations don't take the variability among `VP` groups into account (see the documentation of the [emmeans package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/transformations.html#bias-adj))
- you might want to use `confint()` to get profile confidence intervals rather than the Wald CIs you're using here (or `broom.mixed::tidy(H1_T2x, conf.int = TRUE, conf.method = "profile", exponentiate = TRUE)`)

For plotting, see the `sjPlot` or `ggeffects` or `effects` packages.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the help. With the second suggestion on the profile confidence, tried it and it worked but I now am stuck on how to further use/interpret it.